# How can I write a logical process for finding the area of a point on a graph?

Tags: matlab

I have the following graph with 2 different parameters called p and t.

Their relationship is experimentally found. Manually by knowing (t,p), you can simply find the area number (group) of the point based on where it is located. For example, point M(t,p), locates in area 3 and belongs to group number 3. However, I would like to write a code/logical approach which automatically finds the group numbers. therefore when it reads (t,p) it will find the location of the point and give the group/Area number it belongs.

Is there any solution in Matlab for this scope?  [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLBHI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox and your contours are closed, you can use imfill to fill them up (a bit like the bucket tool in Paint) and assign different values to each filled up region. Does this make sense to you? Let me know if you would like more detail.

Marta